# Why am I getting different simulation results in KiCad every time I run the program?

Tags: ac, simulation, kicad

[image]

I feel like there is something wrong with my circuit. I'm trying to do an AC sweep simulation to find the transfer function frequency response from input to output.

[image]

Comment: What kind of results do you get?  Can you show an example or two?

Comment: I get similar graphs but with different gain values. I was also assigned to tune R3 so that the gain would be similar at 10Hz and 50Hz.

Comment: And R3 is supposed to be 1kOhm :)

Comment: doAnalyses: AC:  Timestep too small; frequency = 0: trouble with xopamp1:jx-instance j.xopamp1.j2

Comment: If you can, try a different, well-known simulator like [LTspice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html).  KiCAD's simulator is fairly new, and while it might work ok in most cases, it is a good idea to also test using a well-known and proven simulator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you do indeed have an error in your circuit:

[image]

You have the output of the op-amp connected to ground.  That's probably not what you wanted.

Given the messages you mention in the comments ("doAnalyses: AC: Timestep too small; frequency = 0: trouble with xopamp1:jx-instance j.xopamp1.j2") you may have a problem with the simulator setup and the op-amp model, as well.  I haven't used the KiCAD simulator, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: Thank you very much! Instantly got a graph that looks smooth.

Comment: This is one of the hazards of using simulators.  It provided a plot of something - and that plot was completely wrong.  In a real circuit, that short to ground would have caused the circuit to fail.  At the very least there would be no output.  At the most the op-amp would quit.  In all cases, though, you'd get  a fairly clear hint that something was drastically wrong.  The simulator just tossed something out - right or wrong.